# Are the security fixes for Cross-Site Scripting introduced in 2.4.5-p1 and 2.4.4-p2 relevant to 2.4.3 systems?

Tags: security, magento2.4.3

Some of our shops are still running on 2.4.3-p3.

From how I understand the most recent security patch notes, the security issues concerning Cross-Site Scripting are only relevant for 2.4.4 and 2.4.5 systems and our older systems are not affected by that problem in partiular. Am I correct in that assumption or did they simply not mention 2.4.3 because their support for those versions will be discontinued in November?

Comment: Can you please tell us that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?

Comment: Hi  @RanaZain. 2.4.5 is affected by the vulnerability and needs to be upgraded to 2.4.5-p1 ASAP. As far as I know the vulnerability has not yet been exploited but it might just be a matter of time.

Comment: So, what you will suggest me to select the version

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Are you asking whether you should be using 2.4.5 compared to other versions of Magento?

Comment: I want to upgrade my site to 2.4.5 it is good to go?

Comment: What version are you currently on? You should definitely test it out before you do it on your live-system. The change from 2.4.4 to 2.4.5 has been very smooth for me. It's a relatively small step. If you are still on 2.43, going to 2.4.4 will be a big step, as it introduces php 8.1. If you go for 2.4.5, remember to go to 2.4.5-p1!

Comment: I am going with the 2.4.5-p1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information on what versions are affected by the vulnerability has been updated on the official site and new hotfixes have been released. For more information check the [security bulletin](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-48.html) and/or [this github-thread](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36294#event-7623017157).